# Recursively find elements in dictionary using an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary, recursion

I have an array:

```py
["a", "1", "2"]
```

and a kinda complex dictionary:

```py
{
  "a":{
    "1": {
      "1": "Some text",
      "2": "This is the text I want",
      "3": "Even more"
    },
    "2": {
      "1": "Some text",
      "2": "More text"
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "1": "Here is some text",
    "2": {
      1: "Some text"
    },
    "3": {}
  }
}
```

How can I use my array, to get `"This is the text I want"`? I'm new to recursion, so I don't really know how to solve this problem correctly

Comment: Is it a requirement to use recursion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be a bit easier:

```
keys = ["a", "1", "2"]
dictionary = {
  "a":{
    "1": {
      "1": "Some text",
      "2": "This is the text I want",
      "3": "Even more"
    },
    "2": {
      "1": "Some text",
      "2": "More text"
    }
  },
  "b": {
    "1": "Here is some text",
    "2": {
      1: "Some text"
    },
    "3": {}
  }
}

for key in keys: # drop to lower level of dictionary with each loop
    try:
        dictionary = dictionary[key]
    except KeyError:
        dictionary = 'ERROR'
        break
    
print(dictionary) # after the loop ends, 'dictionary' will hold the required value
```

Comment: This simplicity is at cost of not handling missing keys

Comment: @Marat thanks for the comment - edited my response with a try/except - this should account for missing keys.

Answer (score 2):

Since the array is in the correct order, at each recursive step you want to use the front of the list to get the next-most-inner dictionary. Something like this:

```
def get_dict(arr, d):
    if not arr:
        return d
    return get_dict(arr[1:], d[arr[0]])
```

A more efficient way would be to reverse the array at the begining, and then take elements from the end, because taking elements from the end is constant time, while taking them from the front is linear (must shift everything over). If you do this, make sure to only reverse it once before the recursion begins.

Comment: recursion level is limited by default + missing keys are not handled

Comment: right, it answers his question exactly, but isn't the best solution

Answer (score 1):

No need for recursion.  A for loop is all you need.

```
array = ["a", "1", "2"]
data = { ... complex data here ... }

current_data = data

for key in array:
    current_data = current_data[key]

print(current_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
address = ["a", "1", "2"]
dict_addresses = {
    "a": {
        "1": {
            "1": "Some text",
            "2": "This is the text I want",
            "3": "Even more"
        },
        "2": {
            "1": "Some text",
            "2": "More text"
        }
    },
    "b": {
        "1": "Here is some text",
        "2": {
            1: "Some text"
        },
        "3": {}
    }
}


def recurse(dict_addresses, address, counter=0):
    if counter == len(address):
        return(dict_addresses)
    dict_addresses = dict_addresses[address[counter]]
    return(recurse(dict_addresses, address, counter + 1, ))


result = recurse(dict_addresses, address)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
This is the text I want
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, yet handling missing keys + no recursion

```
data, path = {...}, ["a", "1", "2"]

while data and path:
    data = data.get(path.pop(0))
```